# Does Argo CronWorkflow support prometheus metrics?

Tags: argoproj, argo-cron-workflows

I'm configuring a CronWorkflow and I'm having issues defining custom prometheus metrics. Running the argo cron lint command, it fails to parse the yaml because of the metrics field

```
failed to parse: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: unknown field "metrics"
```

The more I look into it, it looks like metrics aren't fully supported with CronWorkflows

Comment: Yeah, `metrics` doesn't validate in IDEA with the CronWorkflow CRD installed... have you tried having the CronWorkflow reference a WorkflowTemplate? Just checked, and the field at least validates in a WorkflowTemplate.